# Translate (change) strings in Objective-C (specifically languages)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, lookup

I have this game, that contains a lot of text as speech.  I would like to give the users the option of changing the language of the game to their preferred tongue..  Can anyone point me to a resource or give me a starting point to achieve this?  String look-up table perhaps?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Localizing String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html) in Internationalization Programming Topics. iOS has a built-in system for this using `NSLocalizedString()` and related functions.

See also [String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) in the Resource Programming Guide.

Answer (score 2):

`NSLocalizedString` is of use here. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone) is a simple tutorial on localization.